# Why there is no Lifecycle in Maven that has the goals of Maven Release Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, release, maven-release-plugin

I'm new to the concepts of Maven, In the Default Lifecycle we end with the Deploy Phase, it will deploy a snapshot or a release in the remote repository, it depends on what we have. But how can we move from a Snapshot to a Release? I know that we may use the Release Plugin to do so by doing a release prepare and perform, but why in the Default Lifecycle, there is no phase where we use goals of the release plugin ?

Comment: Simply cause you call the release plugin goals simply as you already mentioned via `mvn release:prepare release:perform`...The other way to move from a snapshot to a release is by changing the version from `WhatEver-SNAPSHOT` to `WhatEver`...Furthermore it's easier to change the maven-release-plugin than the whole maven core....